# Initial sorting of answers and questions

Tags: feature-request, sorting

Hi, how about remembering the sorting of your answers / questions? I personally like to see mine in the 'Newest' sorting, but it's always under the 'Votes' one by default. Sometimes I forget this and it gets confusing when I see my posts in a different order than I instinctively expect them to be.

Thanks!

EDIT:

Here's a screenshot of what I'm talking about. You see how the 'votes' sorting is checked? What I'm asking is that it remembers your last selection when you come back. If you choose 'recent' (which is my preference) it should be like that next time you login.

[alt text http://content.screencast.com/users/CarloDekstop/folders/Jing/media/5cfc2ff4-e8b4-4e31-9444-89d78f60d0b2/2009-09-26_0008.png](http://content.screencast.com/users/CarloDekstop/folders/Jing/media/5cfc2ff4-e8b4-4e31-9444-89d78f60d0b2/2009-09-26_0008.png)

Comment: Waitaminnitjustonesecondlemmegetitstraighthere, you're talking not of the actual question page but the user profile page?

Comment: Am so used to seeing screenshots to better/accurately illustrate a point.

Comment: this is a duplicate request, now.

Comment: duplicate request?

Comment: So is this a no go?

Answer (score 1):

If you're logged in, you should already be able to stick with a sort order.

Having set it a long time ago on Newest, while everyone keeps talking in the mindframe of sort by Votes, this continues to hold true.

Comment: Hmm it doesn't work that way for me. Everytime I log in and go see my posts, they're all sorted by votes.

Comment: I added a screenshot to illustrate my point.